# Moq mocking a function with expression parameters

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, moq

I am having a problem when mocking a function in my IRepository, need help for the code that will mock the function exactly

I tried mocking functions in Moq for any parameter in It object but couldn't resolve

This is the function declarations for ListAsync in my IRepository interface and I need to mock the second one with where and include parameters

`Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> ListAsync(params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] include);`

`Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> ListAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> where, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] include);`

The function is called like :

`var result = await _unitOfWork.XXXRepository.ListAsync(p => p.clientId == clientId);`

The codes that i tried are :

`_unitOfWork.Setup(x => x.XXXRepository.ListAsync(p => It.IsAny<Expression<Func<XXX, bool>>>())).ReturnsAsync(XXXs.AsEnumerable());`

`_unitOfWork.Setup(x => x.XXXRepository.ListAsync(p => Id == id)).ReturnsAsync(XXXs.AsEnumerable());`

`_unitOfWork.Setup(x => x.XXXRepository.ListAsync(p => p.Id == 1)).ReturnsAsync(XXXs.AsEnumerable());`

The interesting thing is the last solution `p=>p.Id ==1` is working when the real function code is like `Where(p=>p.Id ==1)`  but it is NOT working when i get the id as parameter in real function like  `Where(p=>p.Id == clientId)`

I mean I manually prepare the data to return there are 6 items in it and cant get any list item in returning result from mocked function

Any idea for the solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to mock the second overload, you should be able to do this:

```cs
_unitOfWork
    .Setup(x => x.XXXRepository.ListAsync(
        It.IsAny<Expression<Func<XXX, bool>>>(),
        It.IsAny<Expression<Func<XXX, object>>[]>()))
    .ReturnsAsync(XXXs.AsEnumerable());
```

Comment: cool! now how do i sense the parameters coming into the lambda?